# How to read file line by line that may not be valid UTF-8?

Tags: file, rust, vector, utf-8

I have a really large file that *should* consist of JSON strings. However, when I use the following code, I get a "stream did not contain valid UTF8".

```
let file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

for line in reader.lines() {
    println!("{}", line?);
}

Ok(())
```

Now the answer to this is to use `Vec<u8>` rather than `String`. But all the code I've seen has `file.read_to_end(buf)` as the answer which won't work for the filesizes I have to work with.

What I'm looking for is to read the file line by line, use lossy utf8 conversion and then do some calculations and push the output to another file.

Comment: What's the relation with JSON here? Can't you just use [`serde_json::de::StreamDeserializer`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/de/struct.StreamDeserializer.html) in combination with [`serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Deserializer.html#method.from_reader)?

Comment: The size of a file has nothing to do with UTF-8. Either your file is UTF-8 or it's not. "Reading a large file line by line and avoiding utf8 errors" makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BufReader's [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until) function. It is very similar to File's `read_to_end`, but also takes a `byte` delimiter argument. This delimiter can be any byte, and a newline `\n` byte would be suitable for you. Afterwards, you can just lossily convert the buffer from UTF-8. It would look something like this:

```rust
let file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);
let mut buf = vec![];

while let Ok(_) = reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut buf) {
    if buf.is_empty() {
        break;
    }
    let line = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf);
    println!("{}", line);
    buf.clear();
}

Ok(())
```

Of course, this could be abstracted away into an iterator, just like [Lines](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/mod.rs.html#2462-2464) is done, but the basic logic is the same as above.

NOTE: unlike the `lines` function, the resulting strings will include the newline character, and the carriage return (`\r`) if there is one. It will be needed to strip those characters away, if the behaviour of the solution has to match the `lines` function.

Comment: thanks! still getting started with rust so don't know all the functions!